# How to regularly update an an integer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

So I have a String[] which contains math expressions like "3+6=" or "5+9/8=".
I have a function that gets the array, loops through the array and while looping, it splits the array so that I have one String[] containing the math operations like +,-,*,/ and another int[] containing the numbers in the question.

The function then puts the the answer into a int[] called answers. My question is that why when I output the answers[0], I can only see the first number and not the answer to the first question?

EDIT = I have found out that where the problem is happening. It is happening in my evaluation method. I dont know why:

```
public int evaluateAnswerTwoOperations(String operation, int numberOne, int numberTwo) {

    switch(operation){

        case "+":
            Log.d("usingsubtraction","plus2nmbers");
            return numberOne + numberTwo;
        case "-":
            Log.d("usingsubtraction","usingsubtraction");
            return  numberOne - numberTwo;
        case "/":
            Log.d("usingsubtraction","usingdivision");
            return numberOne / numberTwo;
        default:
            Log.d("usingsubtraction","usingmultiplication");
            return numberOne*numberTwo;

    }
```

Comment: Not the problem but your Log.d statements in `evaluateAnswerTwoOperations` are not accurate.

Comment: Can you give an example of input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: @AlLelopath I have a function that generates a random maths expression. So the input is something like "3+4=". The expected output should be 7 but it prints out 12. It always multiplies

Comment: @AlLelopath and sometimes the actual output would print out the first number of the expression

Comment: It would be useful if you log the value of the `operation` parameter. Also, generating strings and then parsing them do not seem like a good design, when you could instead reify operations and operators.

Comment: As @Logain alludes to, the problem is with `operation`. It is always going to the default, not matching "+", "-" or "/". As @Logain also suggests, your approach might not be the best. Consider creating a class with members for `operation`, `numberOne` and `numberTwo`,  that has a method that returns the value the operation on the numbers and `toString` method that returns a String as you would like it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import android.util.Log;

public class TwoNumberOperation {

    private final String PLUS = "+";
    private final String MINUS = "-";
    private final String MULTIPLY = "*";
    private final String DIVIDE = "/";
    private final String EQUAL = "=";

    private String operation;
    private int numberOne;
    private int numberTwo;

    public TwoNumberOperation(String operation, int numberOne, int numberTwo) {
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase(PLUS) ||
                operation.equalsIgnoreCase(MINUS) ||
                operation.equalsIgnoreCase(MULTIPLY) ||
                operation.equalsIgnoreCase(DIVIDE)) {

            this.operation = operation;
            this.numberOne = numberOne;
            this.numberTwo = numberTwo;
        }
        else {
            Log.d("error", "error: invalid operation");
            this.operation = "";
            this.numberOne = 0;
            this.numberTwo = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getAnswer() {

        switch (operation) {

            case PLUS:
                Log.d("addition", "addition");
                return numberOne + numberTwo;
            case MINUS:
                Log.d("subtraction", "subtraction");
                return numberOne - numberTwo;
            case MULTIPLY:
                Log.d("multiplication", "multiplication");
                return numberOne / numberTwo;
            case DIVIDE:
                Log.d("division", "division");
                return numberOne / numberTwo; // note the returning an int
            default:
                Log.d("error", "error");
                return -999999999;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return numberOne + operation + numberTwo + EQUAL;
    }

}
```